# How to retrieve data from ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

i have following code

**In controller**

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request) {
      $data=$request->all();
      //print_r($request->all())
     //return view('main',['data'=>$data]);
     }
 }
```

**In route**

```
Route::get('account/login', function() {
  return View::make('manager.test');
});
Route::post('account/login', 'AccountController@login');
```

**login view**

```
@extends('layout.manager')
@section('content')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Vertical Form Layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.send-btn').click(function(){            
    $.ajax({
      url: 'login',
      type: "post",
      data: {'email':$('input[name=email]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });      
  }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
 <div class="secure">Secure Login form</div>
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'account/login','method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'myform')) !!}
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
     {!! Form::text('email','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'form-control span6','placeholder' => 'Email')) !!}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
  {!! Form::password('password',array('class'=>'form-control span6', 'placeholder' => 'Please Enter your Password')) !!}
  </div>
</div>
{!! Form::button('Login', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
</body>
</html>                                     

@stop
```

when i click submit then all data from ajax will print in my browser console.i have tried to pass ajax value to view in my controller but every time it return 500 internal error.Can anyone tell how to pass ajax value to another view and where i am doing wrong?.
thank you

**Update**

following is not working

```
public function login(Request $request) {
          $data=$request->all();
       $send= User::where('email','=', $data->email)
        return view('main',['data'=>$send]);
         }



public function login(Request $request) {
             return Redirect::to('home');
             }
```

every think working fine .only problem when i return to view.it throw error in my browser console as 500 internal error  otherwise if i print _r inside the controller then it will show data in my browser console.

**update 2**

In my controller

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $data=$request->all();

    return $data;
}

Object { email: "manager@gmail.com", _token: "gqqXvVfwbKRHQWczYNfFMmB9ZB943CLfLdG…" }
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to put your data in content while not having anything in your extends class

Comment: @AdityaGiri.i didnt got what you said

Comment: Put your script above the closing tag of body

Comment: @aldrin27.every think working fine .only problem when i return to view.it throw error otherwise if i print _r inside the controller then it will show data in my browser  console

Comment: @tester I meant to say your view file is messed up. Try to take a look at how it should be organized at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Comment: @AdityaGiri.ya.this is only for testing purpose .

Comment: if you are getting a response in console then it is fine. You need to correctly parse the recieved response.

Comment: @Sourabh.yes you are right.can you tell how to parse that .because if you  see my code .i already tried in controller by returning to view but not working

Comment: @tester don't return the view. Just return `$data` and encode it to json.

Comment: @aldrin27.i have tried that but it only display in browser console not in my page

Comment: Please post your recieved reponse so that i can see and tell you how to parse it

Comment: `Object { email: "manager@gmail.com", _token: "gqqXvVfwbKRHQWczYNfFMmB9ZB943CLfLdG…" }` this part of the code is what you are getting in your console.log response right?

Comment: @Sourabh.yes .console.log response in my browser

Comment: @tester I have tried to answer your question and maybe that's what you really want

Comment: Okie i have posted the answer

Answer (score 2):

In your success callback of your jquery you can access each element of your data object as shown the demo

```
success: function(data){
        alert(data.email);
        alert(data._token);
      }
```

Comment: why do you want to pass data from view to another view using ajax, you can have independent ajax call in each view

Comment: @Sourabh.sorry.i got now where i am doing wrong .lets see if any further error occured

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are doing with your ajax. But I do it like

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_url = $( this ).attr('action');
    var form_data= $( this ).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: form_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( result ){
               $('#result-area').html( result );
        }
    });
});
```

And I get the appropriate response from the form.

And yeah as per your update, if you want that those values should be available in Javascript, you should use `laracasts/utilities` package by Jeffery Way. It's amazing to do that. You could simply do:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
   $data=$request->all();
   $send= User::where('email','=', $data->email);
   Javascript::put([ 'send' => $send ]);
   return view('main');
}
```

And then in your blade you can access by simply saying

```
console.log('send');
```

And it will do the magic.

Comment: @AdAditya Giri. i understood the laravel ajax topic in wrong manner.any way thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the route's problems.

Route:

```
   Route::get('account/login', function() {
       return View::make('manager.test');
    });
   Route::post('account/login', 'AccountController@login');
```

Change that into:

```
    Route::get('account/login, ['as' => 'getLogin, 'uses' => 'AccountController@getLogin']);

   Route::post('account/postLogin, ['as' => 'postLogin', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postLogin']);
```

Controller:

This:

```
    public function login(Request $request) {
      $data=$request->all();
      $send= User::where('email','=', $data->email)
      return view('main',['data'=>$send]);
    }

     public function login(Request $request) {
         return Redirect::to('home');
     }
```

To:

```
   public function postLogin(Request $request) {
      $data=$request->all();
      $send= User::where('email','=', $data->email)
      return $send;
   }

    public function getLogin(Request $request) {
       return Redirect::to('home');
    }
```

Comment: Laravel is confused if that url is post or get from your function so make the functions name to unique if that route is for getting the view or posting the queries.